# Sorting by Date in Shell

Tags: shell

Good day. Ive been trying to sort the following data from a txt file using shell script but as of now I`ve been unable to do so.

Here is what the data on the file looks like,:

```
Name:ID:Date
    Clinton Mcdaniel:100:16/04/2016
    Patience Mccarty:101:18/03/2013
    Carol Holman:102:24/10/2013
    Roth Lamb:103:11/02/2015
    Chase Gardner:104:14/06/2014
    Jacob Tucker:105:05/11/2013
    Maite Barr:106:24/04/2014
    Acton Galloway:107:18/01/2013
    Helen Orr:108:10/05/2014
    Avye Rose:109:07/06/2014
```

What i want to do is being able to sort this by Date instead of name or ID.
When i execute the following code i get this:

Code:

```
sort -t "/" -k3.9 -k3.4 -k3
```

Result:

```
Acton Galloway:107:18/01/2013
Amaya Lynn:149:11/08/2013
Anne Sullivan:190:12/01/2013
Bruno Hood:169:01/08/2013
Cameron Phelps:187:17/11/2013
Carol Holman:102:24/10/2013
Chaney Mcgee:183:11/09/2013
Drew Fowler:173:28/07/2013
Hadassah Green:176:17/01/2013
Jacob Tucker:105:05/11/2013
Jenette Morgan:160:28/11/2013
Lael Aguirre:148:29/05/2013
Lareina Morin:168:06/05/2013
Laura Mercado:171:06/06/2013
Leonard Richard:154:02/06/2013
```

As you can see it only sorts by the year, but the months and everything else are still a little out of place. Does anyone knows how to correctly sort this by date?

EDIT:

Well, I`ve found how to do it, answer below:

Code: `sort -n -t":" -k3.9 -k3.4,3.5 -k3`

Result:

```
Anne Sullivan:190:12/01/2013
Hadassah Green:176:17/01/2013
Acton Galloway:107:18/01/2013
Nasim Gonzalez:163:18/01/2013
Patience Mccarty:101:18/03/2013
Sacha Stevens:164:01/04/2013
Lareina Morin:168:06/05/2013
Lael Aguirre:148:29/05/2013
Leonard Richard:154:02/06/2013
Laura Mercado:171:06/06/2013
Drew Fowler:173:28/07/2013
Bruno Hood:169:01/08/2013
Virginia Puckett:144:08/08/2013
Moses Mckay:177:09/08/2013
Amaya Lynn:149:11/08/2013
Chaney Mcgee:183:11/09/2013
Willa Bond:153:22/09/2013
Oren Flores:184:27/09/2013
Olga Buckley:181:11/10/2013
Carol Holman:102:24/10/2013
Jacob Tucker:105:05/11/2013
Veda Gillespie:125:09/11/2013
Thor Workman:152:12/11/2013
Cameron Phelps:187:17/11/2013
Jenette Morgan:160:28/11/2013
Mason Contreras:129:29/12/2013
Martena Sosa:158:30/12/2013
Vivian Stevens:146:20/01/2014
Benedict Massey:175:02/03/2014
Macey Holden:127:01/04/2014
Orla Estrada:174:06/04/2014
Maite Barr:106:24/04/2014
Helen Orr:108:10/05/2014
Randall Colon:199:27/05/2014
Avye Rose:109:07/06/2014
Cleo Decker:117:12/06/2014
Chase Gardner:104:14/06/2014
Mark Lynn:113:21/06/2014
Geraldine Solis:197:24/06/2014
Thor Wheeler:180:25/06/2014
Aimee Martin:192:21/07/2014
Gareth Cervantes:166:26/08/2014
Serena Fernandez:122:24/09/2014
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort you are using will fail for any date before year `2000` (e.g. `1999` will sort after `2098`). Continuing from your question in the comment, you currently show

```
sort -n -t":" -k3.9 -k3.4,3.5 -k3
```

You should use

```
sort -n -t":" -k3.7 -k3.4,3.5 -k3.1,3.2
```

***Explanation:***

Your `-t` separates the fields on each *colon*. (`':'`) The `-k` *KEYDEF* where *KEYDEF* is in the form `f[.c][opt]` (that's `field.character option`) (you need no separate `option` after `character`). Your date field is (field `3`):

```
  d d / m m / y y y y
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0  -- chars counting from 1 in field 3
```

So you first sort by `-k3.9` (the `9th` character in field `3`) which is the *2-digit* year in the *4-digit* field. You really want to sort on `-k3.7` (which is the start of the *4-digit* date)

You next sort by the *month* (characters `4,5`) which is fine.

Lastly, you sort on `-k3` (which fails to limit the characters considered). Just as you have limited the sort on the month to chars `4,5`, you should limit the sort of the days to characters `1,2`.

Putting that together gives you `sort -n -t":" -k3.7 -k3.4,3.5 -k3.1,3.2`. Hope that answers your question from the comment.

Comment: It did, now i understand what is going on. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: Glad I could help. the `sort -k` explanation in *man sort* left me scratching my head the first couple of times I looked at it too `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You're hamstrung by your (terrible, IMO) date format. Here's a bit of a Schwartzian transform:

```
awk -F'[:/]' '{printf "%s%s%s %s\n", $NF, $(NF-1), $(NF-2), $0}' file | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

That extracts the year, month, day and adds it as a separate word to the start of each line. Then you can sort quite simply. Then discard that date.

Comment: If `sort` let you use a regex as the field separator, you'd be OK, but alas it does not.

Comment: Well i just executed the following code
 sort -n -t":" -k3.9 -k3.4,3.5 -k3
and it worked, I'm not sure how though.